# Как поместить WebView в выпадающее меню (например, Drawer Activity)?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-navigation-drawer

Хочу поместить в выпадающее меню элемент WebView, как показано на рисунке...Второй день не могу разобраться с этой проблемой. Посоветуйте в каком направлении двигаться.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, который остался в итоге, на главном экране я хочу разместить таблицу с элементами, а в на выдвижном экране WebView

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        ...

        <TableRow
            ...
        </TableRow>

        ...

    </TableLayout>/>

</FrameLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private WebView mDrawerWebViewLeft;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayoutLeft;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle("DrawerLayout");

    mDrawerLayoutLeft = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerWebViewLeft = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);


}

/*@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpenLeft = mDrawerLayoutRight.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerLayoutRight);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpenLeft);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}*/
```

}

Comment: Добавьте код в коем вы пытаетесь это сделать но у вас не выходит.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Код добавил

Comment: И что у вас не получилось? В разметке, вроде, всё нормально

Comment: @ЮрийСПб При запуске приложения запускается не таблица, а WebView, и при попытке выдвинуть боковое меню ничего не происходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже вы просто забыли указать выезжающему меню (`Webview`) атрибут `layout_gravity` со значением `start`:

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

Comment: Да, всё отлично получилось. Спасибо

Comment: @ДенисПрищеп, пожалуйста)